# By using DownloadManager how can I see all active/running downloads from my device?

Tags: android

By using DownloadManager how can I see all active/running downloads from my device?

My code:

```
            DownloadManager.Query query = null;
        Cursor c = null;
        DownloadManager downloadManager = null;
        downloadManager = (DownloadManager)m_context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        query = new DownloadManager.Query();
         if(query!=null) 
         {
                    query.setFilterByStatus(DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED|DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED|DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL|
                            DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING|DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING);
         } 
        c = downloadManager.query(query);
        if(c.moveToFirst()) 
        { 
            int status = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)); 
            switch(status) 
            { 
            case DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED: 
            break; 
            case DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING: 
            break; 
            case DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING: 
            break; 
            case DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL: 
            break; 
            case DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED: 
            break; 
            }
        }
```

It's failed on c.moveToFirst() function (returned false);

Does DownloadManager ask some special permision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DownloadManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) documentation says:

> Note that the application must have the INTERNET permission to use
>   this class.

My test app has only **android.permission.INTERNET** and adds download requests well.

```
            // FILL request object
            Uri uri =  Uri.parse( "http://mysite.com/myfile");
            DownloadManager.Request request=new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
            request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
                    .setAllowedOverRoaming(false)
                    .setTitle("my title")
                    .setDescription("my description")
                    ;

            // ADD request to download manager
            DownloadManager dm=(DownloadManager)getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            long id = dm.enqueue(request);

            // CHECK request by id
            Cursor c = dm.query( new DownloadManager.Query().setFilterById(id) );
            if( c.moveToFirst() ){
                int status = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)); 
                switch(status) 
                { 
                case DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED:
                break; 
                case DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING:
                break; 
                case DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING:
                break; 
                case DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL:
                break; 
                case DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED:
                break; 
                }
            }
```

For a successful download there're also should be internet connection, free space on device storage and etc. Anyway the download manager should try to comply download request and explain the user its result.