# Show On Going Download progress in a RecyclerView in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-progressbar, android-download-manager

I am currently working on app where you can download video files. I am using Download manager for downloading files and everything is working fine as the files are being downloaded properly and I can see the progress of downloading in my notifications. Now I want to show those downloading files in another class (containing recyclerview) with the progress. So what should i do to implement this module?

Currently my downloading file code is:

```
public static long fileDownloader(Activity context, Video video) {

    File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/FWV Videos");

    if (!direct.exists()) {
        direct.mkdirs();
    }

    DownloadManager mgr = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

    Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(video.getVideoURL());
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
            downloadUri);


    request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(
            DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI
                    | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
            .setAllowedOverRoaming(false).setTitle(video.getName())
            .setDescription("Downloading file...")
            .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
            .setVisibleInDownloadsUi(false)
            .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/FWV Videos", video.getName() + ".mp4")
            .allowScanningByMediaScanner();
    Toast.makeText(context, "Download started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return mgr.enqueue(request);


}
```

I just want a separate list where i can show on going downloads and completed downloads

Comment: Chek this out : http://stackoverflow.com/a/15162246/244611

Comment: @onurtaskin how can i send those download files' ids to the list? which are being downloaded or in progress?

Comment: `fileDownloader` return the id that you need. Save it somewhere then you can use it.

Comment: Yes i have tried this. The thing is im show list of Files from my `FWV Videos` folder. How can i show both those file and the files which are being downloading in the same adapter.